# How do I add multiple elements to an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I can easily add one element to an existing array:

```
arr = [1]
arr << 2
# => [1, 2]
```

How would I add **multiple** elements to my array?

I'd like to do something like `arr << [2, 3]`, but this adds an array to my array `#=> [1, [2, 3]]`

Comment: `arr.push *another_arr` will add the `another_arr` as flattened values (will not add an array but each value)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Using `+=` operator:

```
arr = [1]
arr += [2, 3]
arr
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Note  that this doesn't add to the array; it creates a new array which is a concatenation of the left and right sides, and assigns it to `arr`.

Answer (score 74):

### Make use of `.push`

```
arr = [1]
arr.push(2, 3)
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

You can also [`.push()`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/push) all elements of another array

```
second_arr = [2, 3]
arr.push(*second_arr)
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

**But take notice!** *without* the `*` it will add the `second_array` to `arr`.

```
arr.push(second_arr)
# => [1, [2, 3]]
```

---

Inferior alternative:

You could also chain the `<<` calls:

```
arr = [1]
arr << 2 << 3
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: suppose you have to push a million items this would not be a good idea.

Answer (score 28):

You can do also as below using [`Array#concat`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-concat):

```
arr = [1]
arr.concat([2, 3]) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 10):

There is several methods to achieve that:

```
array = [1, 2]

array += [3, 4] # => [1, 2, 3, 4]

# push: put the element at the end of the array
array.push([5, 6]) # =>  [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]
array.push(*[7, 8]) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6], 7, 8]

array << 9 # => [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6], 7, 8, 9]

# unshift: put the element at the beginning of the array:
array.unshift(0) #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6], 7, 8, 9]
```

Some links:

- Array in Ruby 1.9.3:
  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/Array.html
- Array in Ruby 2.0.0: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-insert) can add an array to any position:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4,5,6]
b.insert(0, *a)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `.flatten`

for example if you have this array

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and you do this

```
array.push([123,456,789])
array.push([["abc","def"],["ghi","jkl"]])
```

your string would look something like

```
array = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[123,456,789],[["abc","def"],["ghi","jkl"]]]
```

all you need to do is

```
array.flatten!
```

and now your array would like this

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,123,456,789,"abc","def","ghi","jkl"]
```

Comment: Using `flatten` is not the preferred way to do this. Understanding how arrays are concatenated shows that using `+` or `+=` avoids the need to use `flatten` at all. `flatten` is for those times when we get arrays that we didn't generate, or were too lazy to build correctly.

Comment: @theTinMan You're better off using a final `flatten` over an array of arrays built using `push` than using `+=` for every concatenation. You'll get more garbage and more copying with the latter. I'd also expect O(n^2) time from the latter, and O(n) from the former.

Answer (score -1):

One more, for building up an array with items n-times you can use the splat (AKA asterisk, `*`):

```
arr = [true] * 4           # => [true, true, true, true]
```

You can also use the splat for repeating multiple elements:

```
arr = [123,'abc'] * 3      # => [123,'abc',123,'abc',123,'abc']
```

Of course, you can use any array operators with that, such as +:

```
arr = [true] * 3 + [false] # => [true, true, true, false]
```

I use that in conjunction with `#sample` to generate random weighted results:

```
arr.sample                 # => true 3 out of 4 times
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you didn't answer the question OP has asked? He specifically asked for adding values to an existing array, and you showed him how to create an array with repeated n elements.